# Why didn't Kurapika manipulate Uvo to tell him all the information about the Phantom Troupe?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

I've just started watching Hunter x Hunter (2011) and stumbled upon a question on ep. 47. Why didn't Kurapika use the same power as that "Manipulator" woman who made a certain man become her slave by kissing him (or at least a similar technique)... once he mastered all 5 types of Nen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kurapika does not have the ability to use any nen skill regardless of the type. He has the ability to learn any nen skill regardless of type and use it efficiently once has learnt it as if he was that type.  He does not know Baise's nen skill so can't use it.

Her kiss is a specific manipulator skill. There are many different manpulator skills such as the guy fighting with tops you already met.

Comment: (This is an oversimplification as I ignore the specialist category and make it sound easier than it is to master these skills)

Comment: Thanks. But if he was able to master all those techniques in less than 6 months (most of the training was not controlling or creating those chains but mastering the nen)  why doesn't he learn one that resembles that kiss? I know it won't be easy but he's a prodigy once he achieved such results...

Comment: I would if I were him and could. He does have something that seems good enough (do what I say or die with the heart chain thing). Out of universe it was to show how loyal the clearly evil villan was.

Comment: Think you're right... that was what the mangaka tried to emphasize at the end of the day.  Great response. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Kurapica does not have that kind of ability.
Although he could train to get that since nen is tied to character/personality and his nen ability(Emperor Time) gives him 100% use of every category, which means his personality/character would be able to process anything he wishes to. Which ultimately means it's possible if he spends the time.

Key Word: Time.

Kurapica does not have the time or the luxury to train for another skill. He already has 5 chains with different abilities, which speaks for his immense talent. Therefore those abilities take most of his time, polishing them, mastering them into perfection.

Although he has 100% use of manipulation, there's no indication that he trained for it. One can only assume that Kurapica deemed all the 5 chains more worthwhile than the ability to manipulate people like slaves.